# Auto-close navigation on item selection

Tags: javascript

How can I make the below menu close when an item is clicked?

The menu is a fixed sidebar on desktop and is a toggle menu on mobile. This is fine, but the menu takes up half the screen when open and when a nav item is clicked, the page scrolls down to that section but the menu stays open, blocking the content unless you close it but I don't want to add any unnecessary steps for visitors

Thank you

Here's the js

```
//// NAVBAR COLLAPSE
var rNav = $(".right-nav"),
  hInfo = $(".home .info"),
  home = $(".home"),
  navBtn = $(".slide-nav-btn"),
  navBtnActive = "slide-nav-btn-active",
  nav = $(".slide-nav"),
  navActive = "slide-nav-active",
  rNavSpan = $(".right-nav ul li i"),
  up = $(".up i"),
  body = $("html, body");
rNav.css("top", (home.height() - rNav.height()) / 2);
hInfo.css("top", (home.height() - hInfo.height()) / 2);
navBtn.on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass(navBtnActive);
  nav.toggleClass(navActive)

});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="menu navbar-sp">
                <nav>
                    <ul id="navbar">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#home" data-scroll-nav="0" class="active">
                                <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#about" data-scroll-nav="1">
                                <i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> About
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#services" data-scroll-nav="2">
                                <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Services
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#resume" data-scroll-nav="3">
                                <i class="fa fa-gears"></i> Resume
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#portfolio" data-scroll-nav="4">
                                <i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i> Portfolio
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#blog" data-scroll-nav="5">
                                <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> Blog
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#contact" data-scroll-nav="6">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hi T Hall and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take your time to read some of the articles on the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). You should add more code in your question (HTML would help). Good luck!

Comment: you have added event listener to navBtn,just add the same event listners to anchors tag to remove active class from nav on click :)